# View contextual filters to work as needed

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have content type A with some vocabulary for it and content type B with same vocabulary.
On the node page of type A I want to show block with some content of type B wich has any same terms as node page we're viewing. Is it possible?

Thank you!

Comment: short answer, yes. Longer answer depends on your set up. a contextual filter will require that some unique element shared by both (term for example) in the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is extremely easy using Panels as Panels is context aware. You can pass this context to the view, which displays the results based upon the contextual filter.

Look at http://nodeone.se/sv/node/702 and the next episode to get the hang of it.